# oracle node executeMany with dynamic sql query

Tags: javascript, sql, node-oracledb

I am trying to do UPDATE query with executeMany statement. I have tried following with execute in async forEach loop like this:

```
export const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
}
```

then some dynamicDefinitions

```
export const buildDynamicDefs = (data,enumRef) => {
        const defs = {...data};
        Object.keys(defs).forEach(key => defs[key] = enums.typeDefs[enumRef][key])
    return defs;
};
```

then finally execute call

...

```
await asyncForEach(dataArray, async (device) => {
                response[device.deviceId] = await connection.execute(
                    queryPut(device),
                    {
                        bind1,
                        ...device,
                    },
                    {
                        autoCommit: false,
                        bindDefs: {
                            bind1,
                            ...buildDynamicDefs(device,'enumName'),
                        },
                    },
                )
            })
```

and query looks following :

```
export const queryPut = data => `
UPDATE status 
    SET MANDATORY_PROP1=:bind4 
        ${data.bind2 && ',OPT_PROP1=:bind2' || ''} 
        ${data.bind3 && ',OPT_PROP2=:bind3' || ''}
    WHERE MANDATORY_PROP2=:bind1 AND MANDATORY_PROP3=:bind5`;
```

Problem is that when i use executeMany, i do not know how to tell query how should it looks like

```
.executeMany(query,arrayOfObject-binds,options)
```

There is only one query. And my array of objects may looks following:

```
[
 {
  bind1: 1,
  bind4: 4,
  bind5: 5,
 },
 {
  bind1: 1,
  bind2: 2,
  bind4: 4,
  bind5: 5,
 },
]
```

Is there some possibility to optionally add or include that set OPT_PROP1=:bind2 in sql? is there some check for null value of binds?

With execute it is working, but i dont think it is efficient for big numbers of data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation all i needed to do it was change SQL a bit:

```
UPDATE status 
    SET MANDATORY_PROP1=:bind4, 
        OPT_PROP1=COALESCE(:bind2,OPT_PROP1), 
        OPT_PROP2=COALESCE(:bind3,OPT_PROP2),
    WHERE MANDATORY_PROP2=:bind1 AND MANDATORY_PROP3=:bind5`;
```